# Script only applies to elements loaded before Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, show-hide

I have a page consisting of many elements with alphanumeric ids such as this:

```
<li class="entry" id="sjDDulC8wt"> 
   <img src="sjDDulC8wt.jpg" />
   <div class="entry_actions">
      <ul class="entry_actions">
          <li class='share_it'><a href='javascript:' target='_self' 
          title='Share It' class='share_it'>o</a>
          </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="share_options_container"style="display:none;">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#" class="facebook">F</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="twitter">T</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="pinterest">X</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
</li>
```

When I click on the anchor tag under the entry_actions list, it displays the share_options div, and when I mouse out, it disappears again according to this script:

```
$(".share_it a").click(function(){
   $(this).closest(".entry").find(".share_options_container").show();                
})
$(".share_options_container").mouseleave(function(){
   $(this).hide();              
})
```

I also have an infinite scrolling functionality that loads more of these items when the user hits the bottom of the page:

```
var vloaded = <?php echo $i; ?>; //number of items loaded so far
var vfilter = "<?php echo $filter; ?>"; //how I am filtering them

$(document).ready() 
{
  $(window).on('scroll', function () 
    {
      var height = $(window).height();
      var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
      var dHeight = getDocHeight();

      if( height + scrollTop >= dHeight - 10) 
      {
          $.ajax
          (
            {
              type: "POST",
              url: "/organizer/getMore",
              data: { filter: vfilter, loaded: vloaded },
              dataType: "html",
              success: function( responseText, textStatus, XHR )
              {
                // select the element with the ID grid and insert the HTML
                $( "#grid" ).append( responseText );
              }
            }
          );
          // global variable
          vloaded +=30;
      } // if
    }
  ); // on
} // ready
```

For some reason, the show/hide works perfectly fine on the items that are initially loaded, but it does nothing when I click on the ones loaded by the ajax call. From what I can tell, the click event isn't being triggered, but I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$(".share_it a").live("click",function(){
   $(this).closest(".entry").find(".share_options_container").show();                
})
$(".share_options_container").live("mouseleave",function(){
   $(this).hide();              
})
```

You might need to make `.live()` calls to work.

Comment: Wow, that was surprisingly easy. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The click and mouseleave functions are only bound to the elements that exist in the DOM at the time you call the function. If you load up more elements via ajax, then they won't automatically have the event bound to them. You could use either "live" or "delegate" to do this. I prefer delegate.

```
$("ul#entryList").delegate(".share_it a", "click", function(){
   $(this).closest(".entry").find(".share_options_container").show();                
}).delegate(".share_options_container","mouseleave",function(){
   $(this).hide();              
})
```